# Visual Studio Code how to copy colored syntax from terminal

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am running Visual Studio Code on Linux Ubuntu (on virtual machine). The host machine is Windows 10.

Seems VSC for Linux Ubuntu offers some default syntax highlighting for terminal output (at least I do not remember that I have installed any extension for this), as follows:
[image: vsc_bash]

How to copy terminal output to Microsoft Word/Outlook (on host machine) keeping this colourization and formatting? To copy terminal output I am just using `right click mouse` and then `Copy`

Comment: use the Dev tools of VSC and copy that part of the DOM that is the terminal, also copy the used CSS definitions

Answer (score 6):

In v1.66, see the release notes

> Copied text retains HTML styling
>
> To copy rich text from the terminal, run the `Terminal: Copy text as HTML` command or use the terminal context menu entry Copy text as
> HTML.

**BUT** the actual command is:

```
Terminal: Copy Selection as HTML`
```

You have to select your desired text first and then trigger the command.

It is unbound by default, the command is `workbench.action.terminal.copySelectionAsHtml`.

#### You can also right-click and choose `Copy as HTML`.

[image: copy as HTML in terminal]

Comment: thanks for this hint, however seems it does not work on my end. I have updated my VSC from `1.62` to `1.66` with `sudo apt install code` and `Copy as HTML` appeared indeed (in previous version `1.62` it was not available). However copying the terminal output with right-click and choose `Copy as HTML` does not work as I would like it does. I am trying to paste the copied content to Microsoft Word on host machine (Windows10) normally with `Ctrl`+`V` or even `Paste special (Paste as HTML Format)` however result is the same (unformatted text). Do you see any issues in my workflow?

Comment: When you say "unformatted text", what are you expecting?  When I just paste `Ctrl+V` I get the same colors as my terminal shows, same width text.

Comment: this is how it looks like on my end, terminal output copied `Copy as HTML` and pasted `Ctrl`+`V` in Word ![vsc_bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2PVy.png)

Comment: I added a gif to the answer - are you doing anything differently?  If you right-click in the word document and select `Paste Options/Keep Source Formatting` does it work for you?  I don't need to do that though.

Comment: The workflow on my end is the same. `Paste Options/Keep Source Formatting` does not work for me, I do not see any difference between `Keep Source Formatting` and `Merge Formatting` and `Keep text only` which is bit strange for me. Even `Paste Special/HTML Format` (![vsc_bash_word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acTLt.png)) seems to be not working as expected (I am getting unformatted text, without syntax highlighting).

Comment: It no longer seems available

Comment: The right-click option appears to no longer be available - but it works if you use the Windows "dialog" key on the keyboard to open the context menu to get to it!

Comment: The `Copy as HTML` menu option just copies plain text for me (v1.82). Not getting any of the formatting or colors when pasting that anywhere. :-/